# Execute procedure dynamically from another procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle12c

Inside **packA** I have a procedure:

```
procedure testA
is
    v1 varchar2(3200) = 'schema1.packB.test2('''||P1||''','''||P2||''',''Name1'',''Name2'',20,30)';
begin
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v1;
end;
```

when I test it:

```
begin
    packA.testA();
end;
```

I get error: "invalid SQL statement"

But, when I execute v1 from the command line, like:

```
excecute schema1.packB.test2('ABC','DEF','Name1','Name2',20,30);
```

it's working.

I printed `v1` to see what is executed, and looks exactly the same as `"schema1.packB.test2('ABC','DEF','Name1','Name2',20,30)"`

Comment: By 'pack' did you mean 'package'? If so, does 'Execute procedure from pack' mean 'Execute package procedure'?

Comment: yes, package and yes, execute procedure from package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include `BEGIN..END` when running a stored procedure using `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`.

```
    v1 varchar2(3200) = 'BEGIN schema1.packB.test2('''||P1||''','''||P2||''',''Name1'',''Name2'',20,30) END;';
```

`EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` runs an SQL(DML/select) statements or PL/SQL anonymous block

Also, consider using BIND variables instead of PL/SQL variables directly.

```
'schema1.packB.test2( :p1, :p2, :p3, :p4 ,20,30)' USING P1,P2, 'Name1', 'Name2'
```

Comment: Why not even `'schema1.packB.test2( :p1, :p2, :p3, :p4 ,20,30)' USING P1,P2, 'Name1', 'Name2'`?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit : Thanks! I was in a hurry on that occasion.

Answer (score 1):

You need a block to use execute immediate to call a procedure.
For example:

```
SQL> create or replace package pck is
  2      procedure proc;
  3  end;
  4  /

Package created.

SQL> create or replace package body pck is
  2      procedure proc is
  3      begin
  4          null;
  5      end;
  6  end;
  7  /

Package body created.

SQL> begin
  2      execute immediate 'pck.proc;';
  3  end;
  4  /
begin
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
ORA-06512: at line 2


SQL> begin
  2      execute immediate 'begin pck.proc; end;';
  3  end;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Also, while using an execute immediate, consider passing parameters with bind variables. For example, you can (better) re-write the following

```
begin
    execute immediate 'begin pck.proc(''x''); end;';
end;
```

as

```
begin
    execute immediate 'begin pck.proc(:1); end;' using 'x';
end;
```